# How to check if a css/js resource is included in head

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

I'd like to have a function that checks if a resource is included in the head

```
checkIfHeaderHas('myscript.js'); // would return true
checkIfHeaderHas('mystyle.css'); // would return true
checkIfHeaderHas('mybla.css'); // would return false
```

But I'm wondering how I can go about searching the head for a filename? (in the 'src' if it's javascript, or in the 'href' if it's a css)

Comment: So do you just want to know whether they have been *included* in the page or also whether they are fully loaded? Because those are two very different problems.

Comment: For js, you can just define a variable (or constant) inside the .js file, and check if it is defined in the page.

Comment: @Xeon06, included in the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the .length in jquery would work for this. (Not tested!)

Just check to see if a  element exists with the href attribute set to your CSS file's URL:

```
if (!$("link[href='/path/to.css']").length){
alert('not loaded');
}else{
alert('loaded!');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I made a small function that does what you want. It loops through all `<link>` and `<script>` elements until it finds a script with that name. If it doesn't, it returns false.

```
function checkIfIncluded(file) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href.substr(-file.length) == file)
            return true;
    }

    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        if (scripts[i].src.substr(-file.length) == file)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(checkIfIncluded("mystyle.css"));
console.log(checkIfIncluded("myscript.js"));
console.log(checkIfIncluded("mybla.css"));
​
```

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qBhp/)**

**Note that this will not only find resources in the `<head>`, but in thew whole document.** If you really need to look inside the head, tell me and we'll figure something else.

Comment: this works great too, but the traversal wasn't as elegant as the solution i chose

Comment: Nice that it has the benefit of not relying on jQuery

Comment: this should have been the selected answer as the actual selected answer is for `css` only and the selected approach won't work for `js` if the required `js` file is itself a `jquery` file that needs to be checked, +1 for this answer.

Comment: Almost good, but there are problems with resources like `file.js?v=7`. Still +1 for not using jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using jQuery you could maybe do something like:

```
var checkIfHeaderHas = function(fileName) {

    // Start with CSS.
    $.each($("header link"), function() {
        if ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase() === fileName.toLowerCase())
            return true;
    });

    // Then JavaScript.
    $.each($("header script"), function() {
        if ($(this).attr("src").toLowerCase() === fileName.toLowerCase())
            return true;
    });

    // Default response.
    return false;
}
```

Apologies for anything that's not quite right. I'm knocking this out from my phone, and didn't have time to test.

Comment: what if I need to check the `jquery` file itself and if it isn't already loaded won't this one fail at that point. as `$` won't be recognized

Comment: Please notice that despite the (7) upvotes, this doesn't work, it returns always false. Here is a [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419414/how-to-check-if-a-css-js-resource-is-included-in-head/62881024#62881024)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working (tested) solution:

```
function checkIfHeaderHas(name) {
  const checks = [
    {attr: 'href', items: $("head link")},
    {attr: 'src', items: $("head script")}
    // add any other if needed...
  ];
  let res = false;
  if (typeof name === 'string') {
    const lc = name.toLowerCase();
    for (let i = checks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      $.each(checks[i].items, function () {
        if (($(this).attr(checks[i].attr) || '').toLowerCase() === lc) {
          res = true;
          return false; // exit the loop as soon as found
        }
      })
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```